# Memory issue for 'as' in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I'm a noob in Rcpp programming and here is a simple question for Rcpp.
Will it double the memory cost when using 'as' function in Rcpp? Take the following rough codes for an example, 'x' is a very big matrix. I am wondering if 'xx' and 'x' share the same memory or just copy a new memory from 'x'?

```
void test(SEXP x){
    arma::mat xx = as<arma::mat>(x);
}
```

Comment: "It shouldn't".  But you don't have to take my word for it.  You can profile that (if you have memory profiling enabled) and/or benchmark.  See the `examples/` directory of your RcppArmadillo installation.

Comment: Dear Dirk, thanks a lot.